# Using PHP Telegram Bot InputMediaPhoto Method

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I was trying to **send some images into one message** with my Telegram bot. I used **InputMediaPhoto** method to send, but unfortunately doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . "TOKEN" . "/InputMediaPhoto";
$postContent = [
    'chat_id' => $GLOBALS['chatId'],
    'media' => [
        ['type'=>'photo' ,'media' => 'http://www.alcan5000.com/JPG/64Caliente.jpg'], //Just for test
        ['type' => 'photo' ,'media' => 'http://www.alcan5000.com/JPG/64Caliente.jpg'],
        ['type' => 'photo' ,'media' => 'http://www.alcan5000.com/JPG/64Caliente.jpg']
    ]
];
post($url, $postContent);


function post($url, $postContent)
{

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postContent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the post function? I man what response do you receive from Telegram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

The medthod you need to use is called [sendMediaGroup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup). Also the media you are sending must be in a JSON-serialized array.

Changing your code to this should work:

```
 $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . "TOKEN" . "/sendMediaGroup";
 $postContent = [
        'chat_id' => $GLOBALS['chatId'],
        'media' => json_encode([
            ['type'=>'photo' ,'media' => 'http://www.alcan5000.com/JPG/64Caliente.jpg'],
            ['type' => 'photo' ,'media' => 'http://www.alcan5000.com/JPG/64Caliente.jpg'],
            ['type' => 'photo' ,'media' => 'http://www.alcan5000.com/JPG/64Caliente.jpg']
        ])
    ];
```

Comment: Solevd. Thank you!
But How can I send local files?

Comment: @mdarmanam, i have done some Python to send group photo. Please check here, it might give you some idea how to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64800373/8137941