# What is InputMediaPhoto and how to send an array of such resources to Telegram API?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

I'm trying some Google Apps Script script for telegram bot API.

```
  var token = "BOT:TOKEN";
  var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
  var chat_id = "CHAT_ID";
  var image1 = "https://telegram.org/img/t_logo.png";
  var image2 = "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/apps_script_48dp.png";
  
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      "method": "sendMediaGroup",
      "chat_id": chat_id,
      "media": [
        {"type": "photo", "media": image1},
        {"type": "photo", "media": image2},
      ]
    }
  }
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);

}
```

Telegram Bot API Docs said that media type is an Array of `InputMediaPhoto`. But I dont understand. Could anyone help me an example of `inputMediaPhoto` for sending group of photos use sendMediaGroup method?

I did try method `sendPhoto` https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto, it worked. Now i need to send group of photos.

Comment: Can you provide the script of `I did try method sendPhoto https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto, it worked.`?

Comment: `function sendPhoto(chat_id, photo) {`
  `var url = telegramUrl + "/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&photo=" + photo;`
  `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);`
`}`

Comment: Sorry that i don't know how to comment in code format

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could confirm that your token can be used. As the next step, can you provide the detail of result when you run your current script in your question? Because I cannot find it in your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: The result: `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse media JSON object"}`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying comments, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I cannot test this script. I apologize for this. So when that was not the direct solution, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the returned values?

Comment: Your modified script works well. Thank you very much, i'm new so can not promote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your replying comments, I could confirm the following situation.

- Your `token` can be used.
- When your current script is run, the following error message is returned.
  `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse media JSON object"}`

From above situation, I thought that the request body might be required to be sent as JSON. So how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var data = {
  method: "post",
  payload: {
    "method": "sendMediaGroup",
    "chat_id": chat_id,
    "media": [
      {"type": "photo", "media": image1},
      {"type": "photo", "media": image2},
    ]
  }
}
```

To:

```
var data = {
  method: "post",
  payload: JSON.stringify({
    "method": "sendMediaGroup",
    "chat_id": chat_id,
    "media": [
      {"type": "photo", "media": image1},
      {"type": "photo", "media": image2},
    ]
  }),
  contentType: "application/json"
}
```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I need to send group photos into Telegram using Telegram Bot API and couldn't figure out much and have land on this page. Getting some idea from @Tanaike and debug through @pyTelegramBotAPI, I have done some Python code that will send local files to Telegram as group photos. So, I just wanted to share it here to benefit people who facing the same problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests

TOKEN = "random-number:random-alpha-numeric"
CHAT_ID = "-random-number"


request_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TOKEN + "/sendMediaGroup"
params = {
    "chat_id": CHAT_ID
    , "media":
    """[
        {
            "type": "photo"
            , "media": "attach://random-name-1"}, 
        {
            "type": "photo"
            , "media": "attach://random-name-2"}
    ]"""
}

files = {
    "random-name-1": open("/home/pc/Desktop/watermark/data.png", "rb")
    , "random-name-2": open("/home/pc/Desktop/watermark/data.png", "rb")
}

result = requests.post(request_url, params= params, files= files)
print(result.text)
```

Comment: are these names represent post message fields?

Comment: @Michael Quad chat_id and media are post message fields. please check here https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup